# CSS grid alignment of image at bottom corner while still having following text

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid, grid-layout

I want to recreate a grid as shown in the image with css grid. Each image and text below it would represent one article or blog post. I could split the css grid into 4 rows but then I would also need to split the article structure into image and text which I want to avoid. The bottom edges of the two smaller images on the bottom should be aligned with the bottom edge of the big image.

Edit: The text will always have the same amount and Image ratio (4:3) will also be the same.

[image: grid example]

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="post">
    <img src="#" alt="" />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veniam libero
    officiis molestias eveniet odit velit? Fugiat maiores perspiciatis in,
    necessitatibus beatae nobis.
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <img src="#" alt="" />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veniam libero
    officiis molestias eveniet odit velit? Fugiat maiores perspiciatis in,
    necessitatibus beatae nobis.
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <img src="#" alt="" />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veniam libero
    officiis molestias eveniet odit velit? Fugiat maiores perspiciatis in,
    necessitatibus beatae nobis.
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <img src="#" alt="" />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veniam libero
    officiis molestias eveniet odit velit? Fugiat maiores perspiciatis in,
    necessitatibus beatae nobis.
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <img src="#" alt="" />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veniam libero
    officiis molestias eveniet odit velit? Fugiat maiores perspiciatis in,
    necessitatibus beatae nobis.
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 2rem;

  .post {
    &:first-of-type {
    grid-area: span 2 / span 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: always same ratio image? always same amount of text?

Comment: The text will always have the same amount and Image ratio will also be the same. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align the edges of 2 images, you have to target them. There is a new css property called `subgrid` that lets you target the children of the children without breaking the children into several tags. So you can target the images in the main grid without breaking your article HTML structure.

But [according to caniuse, the `subgrid` property is currently only supported by firefox](https://caniuse.com/?search=subgrid).

Here is an example with your HTML and some CSS using subgrid. I have put a `background-color` on images to be able to see them without a real image.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 2rem;
}

.post {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
}

.post:not(:first-of-type) {
  grid-area: span 2 / span 1;
}

.post:first-of-type {
  grid-area: span 4 / span 2;
}

.post:first-of-type img {
  grid-area: span 3 / span 2;
}

.post img {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="post">
    <img src="#" alt="" />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veniam libero
    officiis molestias eveniet odit velit? Fugiat maiores perspiciatis in,
    necessitatibus beatae nobis.
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <img src="#" alt="" />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veniam libero
    officiis molestias eveniet odit velit? Fugiat maiores perspiciatis in,
    necessitatibus beatae nobis.
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <img src="#" alt="" />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veniam libero
    officiis molestias eveniet odit velit? Fugiat maiores perspiciatis in,
    necessitatibus beatae nobis.
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <img src="#" alt="" />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veniam libero
    officiis molestias eveniet odit velit? Fugiat maiores perspiciatis in,
    necessitatibus beatae nobis.
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <img src="#" alt="" />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veniam libero
    officiis molestias eveniet odit velit? Fugiat maiores perspiciatis in,
    necessitatibus beatae nobis.
</div>
```